# How to get extended file-attributes in Windows in Python/Go/C/Batch?

Tags: windows, winapi, filesystems, msdn, file-attributes

I have searched a lot and have got some findings on how to get extended FA, but they are in C# using the language's own built-in APIs. I am trying to find the author name for a file in Windows, but my requirement is in Go/Python/C/Batch (order of priority).

In python, the third party packages (exifread and hachoir_metadata) are not working (not giving any result for a sample doc/xlsx file. Maybe the package I am installing via pip-install is erroneous).

Is there any other way or any user-level MSDN API available?

Please let me know if any experience on this. Thanks.

Comment: You are not talking about NTFS extended attributes. Maybe rename question to something with the property system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, C++ or other language, you get file properties with [IPropertyStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/propsys/nn-propsys-ipropertystore) interface

For example, for a .jpg file (test on Windows 10, VS 2015) =>

I get for **Author** :
 *System.Author(Auteurs) = Test Auteur*

```
PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl = ILCreateFromPath(L"E:\\icon_rose.jpg");
if (pidl != NULL)
{
    IPropertyStore *pps;
    HRESULT hr = SHGetPropertyStoreFromIDList(pidl, GPS_DEFAULT, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pps));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        DWORD dwCount;
        hr = pps->GetCount(&dwCount);
        PROPERTYKEY propKey;
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwCount; ++i)
        {
            hr = pps->GetAt(i, &propKey);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                PWSTR pszCanonicalName = NULL;
                hr = PSGetNameFromPropertyKey(propKey, &pszCanonicalName);                      
                PWSTR pszDescriptionName = NULL;
                IPropertyDescription *ppd;
                hr = PSGetPropertyDescription(propKey, IID_PPV_ARGS(&ppd));
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = ppd->GetDisplayName(&pszDescriptionName);
                    ppd->Release();
                }
                PROPVARIANT propvarValue = { 0 };
                HRESULT hr = pps->GetValue(propKey, &propvarValue);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    PWSTR pszDisplayValue = NULL;
                    hr = PSFormatForDisplayAlloc(propKey, propvarValue, PDFF_DEFAULT, &pszDisplayValue);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        WCHAR wsBuffer[255];
                        wsprintf(wsBuffer, L"%s(%s) = %s\n", pszCanonicalName, (pszDescriptionName==NULL?L"Unknown":pszDescriptionName), pszDisplayValue);
                        OutputDebugString(wsBuffer);
                        CoTaskMemFree(pszDisplayValue);
                    }
                    PropVariantClear(&propvarValue);
                }
                if (pszCanonicalName != NULL)
                    CoTaskMemFree(pszCanonicalName);
                if (pszDescriptionName != NULL)
                    CoTaskMemFree(pszDescriptionName);;                         
            }
        }                   
        pps->Release();
    }
    ILFree(pidl);
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the information, but unfortunately the call to SHGetPropertyStoreFromIDList() is always failing (hr = -2147221008).
Any suggestion regarding that.

Comment: Thsi error is **CO_E_NOTINITIALIZED**, so you must initialize COM first, like :  `HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
   if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
   {
    // Code...
   }`:

Comment: Thanks again, mate. But unfortunately, I am not getting the Author name. Following are the attributes that I receive.

`System.ItemFolderNameDisplay
System.ItemTypeText
System.ItemNameDisplay
System.Size
System.FileAttributes
System.DateModified`

I have checked. The doc file contains the author.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem...
I just tested with a random .doc file with those [Doc Props](https://i.ibb.co/zs7hfpy/docprops.jpg) (french)
I get 87 properties and one of them is **System.Author(Auteurs) = Truß, Johannes**, like in the properties dialog box

Comment: My code is an almost full copy paste of yours.
https://ideone.com/7bwTcf

On Windows 10 I am testing.

Could you also send your complete code?

Comment: I uploaded a Win32 console test program with the .doc file I tested (VS 2015 project) => [Test_IPropertyStore.zip](https://app.box.com/s/ofgltk26od3joqahgtm53eszrkpxguc6)